# Dúvida sobre ambiente de desenvolvimento LAMP com Vagrant e provisionamento com Puppet

Tags: php, vagrant, lamp

Depois de alguns problemas em relação à incompatibilidade de aplicações, desenvolvidas localmente, com o servidor, resolvi utilizar a ferramenta [*Vagrant*](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

Segui alguns tutoriais, li sua documentação, criei minha máquina virtual e tive problemas com o provisionamento (creio eu que por falta de entendimento do funcionamento da mesma).

Enfim, encontrei [uma trilogia de artigos muito bom](http://erikaheidi.com/blog/a-begginers-guide-to-vagrant-getting-your-portable-development-e) (pelo menos eu achei rs) que me ajudou bastante a entender como funcionava o provisionamento com o [*Puppet*](https://puppetlabs.com/).

Mas ainda assim, tenho algumas dúvidas e venho aqui perguntar aos que já trabalham com essas ferramentas, se podem esclarecê-las.

Algumas delas são:

1. Em um ambiente de desenvolvimento com *Vagrant*, é necessário instalar um sistema de controle de versões como o [*GIT*](https://git-scm.com/) dentro da VM? Se sim, Por que?
2. Sou iniciante no uso do [*Composer*](https://getcomposer.org/), e estou entusiasmado, querendo utilizar esta ferramenta em meus projetos, é necessário instalá-lo na VM também? Se sim, Por que?
3. O que seria preciso instalar além do básico (*Apache*, *PHP*, *MySQL*)?

Bom pessoal, as principais dúvidas que me surgiram foram essas.

Agradeço desde já a atenção dispensada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Em um ambiente de desenvolvimento com Vagrant, é necessário instalar um sistema de controle de versões como o GIT dentro da VM? Se sim, Por que?

Depende. O Vagrant tem um funcionamento básico de compartilhamento de uma pasta na sua máquina física com a máquina virtual. Você pode:

- Utilizar o GIT na sua máquina física para versionar seu projeto
- Utilizar o GIT na máquina virtual

Basicamente, tanto faz. Mas é importante lembrar que o uso do Vagrant não substitui o uso de um software de versionamento. Talvez se você estiver trabalhando sozinho em um projeto, sinta-se como se não houvesse a necessidade de utilizar versionamento, no entanto é sempre bom manter-se atualizado diante das ferramentas para que você não tenha que aprender muita coisa nova se começar um projeto em parcerias.

> Sou iniciante no uso do Composer, e estou entusiasmado, querendo utilizar esta ferramenta em meus projetos, é necessário instalá-lo na VM também? Se sim, Por que?

Basicamente o mesmo conceito anterior se aplica. Você poderia instalar o Composer só na máquina física e gerenciar seu projeto por lá ou instalar na máquina virtual.

Particularmente, sugiro instalar todas as ferramentas de desenvolvimento no Vagrant. Por quê?

- Qual a utilidade do Composer na sua máquina física?
- Qual a utilidade do GIT na sua máquina física?

Se a resposta para ambas as perguntas é apenas **gerenciar meu projeto que está rodando dentro do Vagrant**, então você simplesmente está *sujando* o ambiente da sua máquina física ao invés de tirar um maior proveito da máquina virtual.

> O que seria preciso instalar além do básico (Apache, PHP, MySQL)?

É importante instalar as ferramentas básicas que você utilizará para trabalhar. O Laravel, por exemplo, oferece uma Vagrant chamada Homestead que vem com PHP 7, MySQL, Nginx (ao invés do Apache), Composer, Git, Mencache, Sqlite 3, etc...

Talvez seja melhor não se preocupar com o que mais precisa instalar além das ferramentas básicas. Quando surgir a necessidade, você saberá o que mais instalar.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos Marco! Ajudou bastante o/